# ChromeOS kiosk limitations: bypass framekiller

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os, kiosk-mode, chromebook

I'm developing a ChromeOS kiosk application (website + chrome extension) which suppose to run in Kiosk Mode on managed Chromebook devices. Application displays external web content which I don't own, I'm using sandboxed `iframe`s to display that web content. These external websites should not escape their `iframes`, that's why I sandbox them. The app is basically a simple web browser but instead of tabs I use `iframes`, and the top frame (`window.top`) is the wrapper around these iframes.
With all ChromeOS technical limitations I was able to bypass most of the iframe checks (x-frame-options, csp, blocked 302...) using the extension. However there is one I'm stuck with - framekillers. I can't properly display websites which do `self !== top` type of checks.

Is there a way to bypass it too somehow? I'm fine with refactoring my app completely or use something else instead of `iframe`. The app has to fulfil only one condition though - kiosk mode on a managed chromebook.

It's unfortunate that Chrome Apps with `<webview>` tag were deprecated and Android apps can't run in Kiosk mode anymore. This would solve all my issues easily by just using something else than `iframe`s.

I've tried injecting the following buster `<script>` via a content script but it doesn't seem to work, websites seems to be doing something more advanced.

**buster.ts**

```js
function buster() {
  if (top !== self) {
    (window.self as any) = window.top;
    (window.parent as any) = window.top;
  }
}
buster();
```

**content-script.ts**

```js
const b = document.createElement('script');
b.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('buster.js');
const el = document.head || document.documentElement;
el.insertBefore(b, el.firstChild);
console.debug('buster is injected');
```

Comment: 1) Your script runs too late because you use `src`. In MV2 extension you should use textContent (see [method 2](/a/9517879)). In MV3 the only current solution (aside from `chrome.debugger` API + Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnLoad) is chrome.scripting.registerContentScript with `world: 'MAIN'`. 2) Maybe the site uses `window == top` which is impossible to override. 3) Try [fenced frames](https://github.com/WICG/fenced-frame/blob/master/explainer/README.md), currently in trial, but eventually it'll be enabled by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution based on @wOxxOm comment (for MV3 extension):

**background.ts**

```js
chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts([
  {
    allFrames: true,
    id: 'some-id',
    js: ['buster.js'],
    matches: ['<all_urls>'],
    runAt: 'document_start',
    world: 'MAIN',
  },
]);
```

**buster.ts**

```js
function buster() {
  if (top !== self) {
    (window.self as any) = window.top;
  }
}
buster();
```